# How to revoke Application permission on a user profile programatically using PHP SDK v5.x for Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am new to Facebook Application development.

At a point in my App, I want to revoke the permission that my App have on the user's profile.

At this time 
I want to Run a code that will take back all the set permissions for the App on the user's profile.

I have searched the web and I found:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking
```

I want to see some working code to revoke all the permissions that my App has on this user's profile.

What is the delete endpoint and how do I call it ?

I have tried to do this:

```
$response = $fb->delete("/permissions", $_SESSION['fb_access_token']);
```

But this does not work, it gives me the folloowing error:

"

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Facebook\Facebook::delete() must be of the type array, 
string given, called in /index.php on line 454 and defined in Facebook/Facebook.php:383 
Stack trace: #0 /index.php(454): Facebook\Facebook->delete('/permissions', 'ahkadhkdhkdahkadhs...') 
#1 index.php(102): step2_sub_step3(Object(Facebook\Facebook)) #2 {main} thrown in Facebook/Facebook.php on line 383
```

"

Comment: I know what are endpoints, but I want to know the correct way to call this endpoint using Facebook SDK for PHP v5.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, the actual endpoint is

```
DELETE /{user-id}/permissions
```

And, the method signature is

```
public function delete($endpoint, array $params = [], $accessToken = null, $eTag = null, $graphVersion = null);
```

So your code would look more like this:

```
$response = $fb1->delete("/" . $userID . "/permissions", [], $_SESSION['fb_access_token']);
```

Notice that you need to get the user's ID first. Or, if the user is already logged in, you can use

```
$response = $fb1->delete("/me/permissions", [], $_SESSION['fb_access_token']);
```